# Cannot connect to Windows through LAN as a guest. Says RPC struct is bad

Tags: windows, iphone, ios

My Iphone says "The operation could not be completed. RPC struct is bad. " while trying to connect to my Windows in the same LAN.
I also tried connecting using other Mac, Android and Win, they all failed.

Comment: Do a Windows 10 Repair Install on the faulty machine and see if that lets you connect - at least from the other Windows machines